# why use Sockets when we have UrlConnection

Tags: java, android, ios, sockets, networking

I have read many posts on stackoverflow on regarding socket vs. URLConnection , and it appears that there is not much difference. Can someone tell me what advantage is there to going low level (socket programming) ?

Answer (score 1):

Because URLConnection assumes a small set of predefined protocols.  Generally when doing socket programming you are writing your own protocol.  While you can register additional protocols, doing so is a large pain and your custom protocol may not fit well into the URLConnection system.  Using pure sockets is more flexible and easier to handle.  So unless you're using one of the predefined protocols there's no reason to use URLConnection.

Comment: can you give me practical example of why we would want to write our own protocol ?

Comment: You're looking to be efficient.  A protocol decreases the time it takes to write code at the cost of efficiency and flexibility to handle different use cases.  In particular the common protocols like HTTP and FTP are really only good for transfering files-  it's what they were made for.  They're horrible for bidirectional communication.

Comment: So URLConnection uses exiting protocols (http) and with sockets you make a custom protocol (Or non at all I guess?). Does that mean you cannot create sockets and surf the web with them - unless you make a custom protocol that is exactly thesame as http? (Which then would be completely unnecessary beacuse the http feature already exists within URLConnection)

Answer (score 0):

There are well defined layer 7 application protocol for most of the server/client communication. There is only a little need to use low level socket programming for an application. With socket layer, you get the advantage of tweaking the socket parameters to fine tune it to your application need. Suppose you need a faster request response, you can set the TCP_NODELAY socket option to avoid the 200ms delay between the response. Likewise, there are few socket option which can be tweaked for special need for an application which otherwise is not possible with URLConnection